# Добавление записей в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

В самом начале своего плагина ставлю такой код:

```
echo 1;
$id = wp_insert_post([
    'post_title'    => 1,
    'post_content'  => 2,
    'post_status'   => 'publish', // publish или draft
]);
echo 2;
$id = wp_insert_post([
    'post_title'    => 2,
    'post_content'  => 3,
    'post_status'   => 'publish', // publish или draft
]);
echo 3;
exit;
```

При этом первый пост добавляется, а второй нет. Также выводится на экран "1", а дальше ничего нет, даже сообщения об ошибке.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: $id это что такое ? если это идентификатор - то таковой должен быть один на всю страницу

Comment: @МаксимЛенский это идентификатор (номер поста) или объект WP_Error. К html #id не имеет никакого отношения.

Comment: @KAGGDesign  я не знал этого ...спс за пояснения

Comment: Очевидно, что код падает внутри первого вызова `wp_insert_post()`, после помещения поста в базу, на выполнении хуков. Скорее всего, дело в том, что нельзя вот так "в лоб" помещать вставку поста в тело плагина, надо его выполнять по какому-то событию, например, init. Но это все гадание на кофейной гуще. Как можно писать код, не включив отладчик или хотя бы отладочную информацию? Почитайте на русском, как использовать стандартные средства отладки в WP: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html Когда вернётесь с сообщением об ошибке, можно будет обсудить ваш случай предметно.

Comment: KAGG Design спасибо! вы правы!!